# Return all column names for a duplicate value in a table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I would like to know is it possible to return all value for duplicate column with same ID value for oracle sql

My table design would below

Table A

```
Name    ID      Order       Year
------  ------  -------     ------
JOHN    1       ORD123      2017
JAKE    2       ORD122      2018
JES     2       ORD111      2017
JOHN    3       ORD323      2012
NICK    4       ORD133      2011
AMY     4       ORD222      2010
MUS     4       ORD132      2010
```

I want the result of the query to be as below

```
Name    ID      Order       Year
------  ------  -------     ------
JAKE    2       ORD122      2018
JES     2       ORD111      2017
NICK    4       ORD133      2011
AMY     4       ORD222      2010
MUS     4       ORD132      2010
```

Comment: Sure thing it is possible, you could do it with a subselect or a `group by having count('X') > 1`. Anyway this is a common problem and is pretty much already answered in stackoverflow

Comment: I would suggest you marking the question that [you think is best as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) If you hadn't tried I would encourage give [mt0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51781775/2265446) a go. ATM all three answers should solve your problem.

Comment: yeah u right alll was working... i could only choose 1 option that kind sad... as all 3 was good. thanks guys

Comment: IMHO, the purpose of the accepted answer is flag an answer as "most helpful/the best answer to the original poster/OP". That way is easy to differentiate from a group of related questions those with a working answer and go directly to the best approach/answer. If a question has multiple working/useful answers or not usefull answers, those can be detected with the upvotes or downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an analytic function to do it in a single table scan:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b978/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA ( Name, ID, "Order", Year ) AS
  SELECT 'JOHN', 1, 'ORD123', 2017 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JAKE', 2, 'ORD122', 2018 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JES',  2, 'ORD111', 2017 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JOHN', 3, 'ORD323', 2012 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'NICK', 4, 'ORD133', 2011 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AMY',  4, 'ORD222', 2010 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MUS',  4, 'ORD132', 2010 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Name, ID, "Order", Year
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ) AS num_duplicates
  FROM   tableA t
)
WHERE  num_duplicates > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b978/3/0)**:

```
| NAME | ID |  Order | YEAR |
|------|----|--------|------|
| JAKE |  2 | ORD122 | 2018 |
|  JES |  2 | ORD111 | 2017 |
| NICK |  4 | ORD133 | 2011 |
|  AMY |  4 | ORD222 | 2010 |
|  MUS |  4 | ORD132 | 2010 |
```

Using `IN ( SELECT ... GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )` or an aggregation in a self-join will require two table/index scans.

---

**Update**

> if i have two condition, is it posisble also, maybe id and year?

**Query 2**: Just add the additional columns to the `PARTITION BY` clause:

```
SELECT Name, ID, "Order", Year
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY id, year ) AS num_duplicates
  FROM   tableA t
)
WHERE  num_duplicates > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b978/4/1)**:

```
| NAME | ID |  Order | YEAR |
|------|----|--------|------|
|  AMY |  4 | ORD222 | 2010 |
|  MUS |  4 | ORD132 | 2010 |
```

Comment: if i have two condition, is it posisble also, maybe id and year?

Comment: Adding the year into the equation it would be `COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY id, YEAR) AS num_duplicates`. That way the analytic function would reset (would recount) for each ID-YEAR pair.

Comment: thanks for all you in making me understand and helping me

Answer (score 2):

Have a sub-query to return id's that exists more than once.

```
select *
from tableA
where id in (select id from tableA
             group by id
             having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: @bradbury9, I did ask myself the same question. Actually I don't know if Oracle optimizes the queries different or not. Someone can perhaps check the execution plan.

Comment: I think it could be pretty similar or the same, one table scan for the duplicated ID's and the table scan for the data retrieval. For readability I prefer a join.

Comment: can i know why count(*) instead of coun(id)?

Comment: @james, `count(*)` counts rows (for each id). `count(id)` counts non-null id values (for each id.) Same result in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with either a subquery in the where clause or with a join between the duplicated ID's and the main table. For the subquery approach check jarlh's answer.

I think that for large tables you shuld make sure the table is correctly indexed.

```
select 
    a.*
from 
    (
         select id from tableA group by id having count(*) > 1
    ) dupes
    inner join TableA a dupes on a.id = dupes.id
```

Comment: can i know why count(*) instead of coun(id)?

Comment: this is better for performance part since it a large amount very large amount  of recrods in the table?

Comment: @james Long time ago it did matter, nowadays it is not a problem performance wise. You could also `count('X')` with the same results.

Comment: ic... so the count no matter can be anything right?

Comment: @james the result could vary if the column admits null values. Performance wise, doesnt matter. I like to `count('X')` or `count(*)` to avoid referencing columns that could change its name in the future and break the SQL

Comment: "Result could vary if the column admits null value". This means that if null value count (id) wil lnto work?

Comment: This TSQL `declare @table table(col int null);insert into @table(col)values(1),(null),(2),(2),(3);select count(col) from @table` it will return `4`. In the OP use case it does not matter because the OP data has no nulls and wants to check for duplicated ID's (its spected to not have nulls).

Comment: @james `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` (or any literal value instead of `1`) are identical and will count the total number of rows in the group. `COUNT(id)` will count the number of non-null `id` values within the group. If your `id` column has no null values then the result will be identical but if your `id` column has `null` values then `COUNT(*)` will be higher than `COUNT(id)` for those groups with null values.

Comment: @MT0 Thats what I tried to show with the tsql sample.

Comment: This isn't a TSQL question and it wasn't clear to me what the point of that code snippet was (especially since Oracle's dialect of SQL and SQL server's dialect of SQL have subtle differences). I thought it deserved a more explicit comment, especially with hotfix's erroneous comment on never using `*` (or at least it is advice that is deprecated by many versions of Oracle).

Comment: @MT0 Agree, thats why I stated "Long time ago it did matter, nowadays it is not a problem performance wise". That behaviour is identical in TSQL and PL/SQL but im more used to TSQL, hence the language choice. Anyway I appreciate your more elaborated comments (and upvoted your question, because of the single table scan)

Comment: if i have two condition, is it posisble also, maybe id and year?

Comment: @james indeed, change the `group by` and the `inner join` to take into account both fields. In MT0's answer you would have to add the year to the `partition by` clause

Comment: It can look weird, but the only reason im not deleting this question is to show multiple working choices. The best performance would probably be MT0's answer. Analytic functions for begginers could be hard to understand. I would  encourage reading abou them cause they are powerful